# PHP 5.3.19: Class 'DOTNET' not found

Tags: php, .net, dll

When I try to load a DLL using the `DOTNET()` function I get the above error. However, I have .NET installed on my server (I can verify in IIS) and I have also enabled the php_com_dotnet.dll extension in my php.ini file.

This is what it looks like:

```
[PHP_COM_DOTNET]
extension=php_com_dotnet.dll
```

However I still get this error. (If it matters, I am not using one of windows's DLL's. It's a 3rd party one that I have obtained)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why i was getting this error is because i was editing the WRONG php.ini file. If you develop PHP in visual studio with the php plugin, you have a separate ini file to work with. It is that one that i had to change to get this to work rather than the .ini file in IIS.